# How can i disable aggregation in ag-grid pivot mode?

Tags: ag-grid

These are the options given by grid, I want to hide the aggregation part as I don't have any columns to be aggregated.

[image: Menu from ag-grid with aggregate values section highlighted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `gridOptions.toolPanelSuppressValues: true`

You can read more about suppressing other portions of the toolpanel [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0) (look for **Suppress Example**)

Comment: for Row Groups use this -> toolPanelSuppressRowGroups: true

Answer (score 1):

In ag grid 23 you have to do it inside `sideBar` options of `GridOptions` property.

```
toolPanels: [
      {
        id: 'id',
        labelDefault: 'labelDefault',
        labelKey: 'labelKey',
        iconKey: 'iconKey',
        toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        toolPanelParams: {
          suppressPivotMode: true, - here
          suppressValues: true,
        },
      },
    ],
```

Comment: Here's all available options: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/tool-panel-columns/#section-visibility